# How to change contact colors with Messages 3.5?

Tags: sms, color

I used to be able to change my contact/conversation color in Android Messages. With that latest update I can't find this feature. Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change it. There is an ongoing discussion in [Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/phone-by-google/zN6UsmdXs9A). You can give a feedback there as also from the app

OR

uninstall this and find the previous version apk and install that  / change the SMS app